# A way to launch x applications as administrator automatically (Windows xp)

Tags: permissions, windows-xp, administrator

The problem is that in our clients their normal user doesn't have administrator privileges so when they have to install or update our programs they have to log again as administrator to install them and then log as their user which is cumbersome...

As some updates are automatic the "run as" solution isnt a valid one...

One good idea would be to mark a folder as "admin folder" so all the exes executed from that folder run as administrator (having configured the admin account previously) 
or a configurable a list of executable names that must run as administrator (i say names because it could be different installers with different hash but with a generic exe name that identifies it as ours)

Does anyone know a program or windows configuration or c# code to achieve something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't a list of executable names to be always executed as an administrator be quite the security hole? You might as well give all the users admin privileges if you do that...

Comment: I prefer the "admin folder" idea but if worst goes worst...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems nobody knows how to do it or doesnt want to tell because its a security hole...ironically having this escalating privileges hole would be better than having the user as administrator for everithing :S... (Appart from not being a valid solution for our clients)